# Groovy LIST concatenation with null check. Limitation of elvis operator?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I attempted to add lists, where list may not be present with a concise code. Think "defaultConfig" and "userConfig".

Demonstration:

```java
listA = ['a']
listB = ['b']
    
println listA + listB ?: []
println listB ?: [] + listA

// This results in:

[a, b]
[b]
```

1st statement behaves as expected, while 2nd is not.
And simple mathematical truth `a+b=b+a` is not true in this case.

...And if we change single value to `null`,

```
listA = ['a']
listB = null

println listA + listB ?: []
println listB ?: [] + listA

// Results in:

[a, null]
[a]
```

Now it is opposite, 2nd statement behaves as expected, while 1st is not!

Questions:

1. Is the elvis operator good for assignment only?
2. Is there another, better inline way to fallback to empty list if value is null?

P.S. This is being run in latest version of Jenkins, which still uses Groovy 2.4

Comment: Remember operators precedence.  Elvis operator precedence is above assignment and below everything else, including +

Comment: Thank you. Adding link: https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence